# Are there any PHP DocBlock parser tools available?

Tags: php, documentation, parsing, docblocks

I would like to build some smaller scale but hightly customized documentation sites for a few projects. [PhpDocumentor](http://phpdoc.org/) is pretty great but it is very heavy. I thought about trying to tweak the templates for that but after spending only a couple of minutes looking into it I decided that it would be too much work.

Ideally I'd like to see something to which I could pass a bunch of files and have it return all of the files, classes and properties and methods, along with their meta data, so that I could build out some simple templates based on the data.

Are there any DocBlock parser-only projects that will help me in this task, or am I stuck reinventing that wheel?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do this easily yourself with the [Reflection API:](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php)

```
/**
 * This is an Example class
 */
class Example
{
    /**
     * This is an example function
     */
    public function fn() 
    {
        // void
    }
}

$reflector = new ReflectionClass('Example');

// to get the Class DocBlock
echo $reflector->getDocComment()

// to get the Method DocBlock
$reflector->getMethod('fn')->getDocComment();
```

See this tutorial: http://www.phpriot.com/articles/reflection-api

There is also a [PEAR package](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Parser_DocblockParser) that can parse DocBlocks.

Comment: To use reflection, don't you somehow have to load the PHP script containing the class of interest?   How do you accomplish that, for an arbitarily long list of PHP scripts?

Comment: @Ira See the example at http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php - if you want to parse files for classes, you can use http://github.com/theseer/Autoload/blob/master/src/classfinder.php and to iterate over directories you can use http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

Answer (score 6):

In case someone needs a regular expression ([xdazz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/762073/xdazz) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12235831/367456) to try this and [student310](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288927/student310) commented it works for her/his needs)

```
if (preg_match_all('/@(\w+)\s+(.*)\r?\n/m', $str, $matches)){
  $result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
}
```

***Example ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/DeFL3V))***:

```
<?php
$str ='
/**    
 * @param   integer  $int  An integer
 * @return  boolean
 */
';
if (preg_match_all('/@(\w+)\s+(.*)\r?\n/m', $str, $matches)){
  $result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
}

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 5):

Just to update the answers. You may also want to check out the [phpDocumentor2](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2) project. I think that it's PHP DocBlock parser can be easily extracted as standalone solution.

Comment: DocBlox has merged with phpDocumentor to become [phpDocumentor2](http://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2).

Comment: Although I agree that phpDocumentor is good, the OP explicitly asks for something that **isn't** phpDocumentor

Answer (score 3):

As furgas [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7771772/185371), I've been using [phpDocumentor](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/ReflectionDocBlock) for years as a standalone project and it works fine.

```
<?php
$class = new ReflectionClass('MyClass');
$phpdoc = new \phpDocumentor\Reflection\DocBlock($class);

var_dump($phpdoc->getShortDescription());
var_dump($phpdoc->getLongDescription()->getContents());
var_dump($phpdoc->getTags());
var_dump($phpdoc->hasTag('author'));
var_dump($phpdoc->hasTag('copyright'));
```