# Parse PHP docblocks into structured variables

Tags: php

Generally we add the comment's on classes and function to explore the class and its functions.

**LIKE:**

```
/**
 * some descriptions
 * @params
 */
  class NewClass {
      /**
        * method description
        * @params
        */
      public function first(){

      }

      /**
        * method description
        * @params
        */
      public function second(){

      }
  }
```

I want to retrieve the comments on the PHP CLASS and RESPECTIVE CLASS FUNCTIONS.

Can anyone help me??

```
   The required output is::

array(0=>array( 'type'=>'class','comment'=>"/*** some descriptions* @params*/"),
      1=> array( 'type'=>'method','comment'=>"/*** method description* @params*/"),
      2=> array( 'type'=>'method','comment'=>"/*** method description* @params*/")
);
```

Comment: Can you please clarify (the question is impossible to understand in its current form). Are you talking about DB comments? Or the comments inside the PHP class files? And also post some code on what you already tried?

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: Good question indeed.. @user3305818 Before you start reinventing the wheel (or even the world one day) - I suggest using http://www.phpdoc.org/ - if your plan is to extract doc blocks of PHP class files. Looking at their source code might also be the best way of finding out how it's done. In case you still want to (re)invent it on your own.

Comment: Or you need to get it from a file_get_contents() ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From another stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531085/are-there-any-php-docblock-parser-tools-available)

TLDR: version use the [Reflection API](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php)

Comment: Well spot. But it should be a duplicate question, not a duplicate answer ;-)

Comment: I have used the Reflection API and got Success. Refer the another stack overflow question link for more details. The link is in answer by **CoolGoose**.